# c++ Algorithm remove duplicates - both values

Tags: c++, algorithm

**EDIT NOTE: This is not a code review, rephrased the question.**

Discussion on algorithm implementation at: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/80412/c-algorithm-remove-duplicates-both-values

My Special case:
Home Project, Automatic Downloader for Podcasts.

Overall Algorithm is:

1. Download a list of available podcasts
2. hash the podcasts
3. load metadata + hash of downloaded podcasts from sqlite db
4. Algorithm this questions is about -  throw out all already downloaded.
5. Download new podcasts
6. save metadata to sqlite db

**Note this algorithm works only to remove 2 duplicates, if there are more than 2 it breaks, please look at the overall algorithm.**

**Question: is there a name for this algorithm 4 or an aquivalent algorithm?**

**Question: are there different approaches than my example code below**

As a discussion basis the code 
Requirements: c++11 compiler e.g gcc 4.9
note: copy paste ready code.

`#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

template <typename ForwardItr>
ForwardItr doubleEraser(ForwardItr first, ForwardItr last)
{
 auto itr = first;
 typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardItr>::value_type firstMatch = *first;
 bool hasFirstMatch(false);

 while(itr != last)
 {
  auto next = std::next(itr);
  if(next != last && *itr == *next)
  {
    if(!hasFirstMatch)
    {
     hasFirstMatch = true;
     firstMatch = *itr;
    }
    else
    {
     if(*itr == firstMatch) // again at first match
     {
       return itr; 
     }
    }


    std::rotate(itr, std::next(itr, 2), last); // throw matched elements to the end of container
   }
   else
    ++itr;
  }
 return last;
}

template <typename T>
void print(T& c)
{
 for(auto & element : c)
  std::cout << element << " ";

 std::cout << "\n";
}

template <class T>
void process(std::vector<T>& t)
{
  std::string formating(" \t");
   std::cout << "input: " << formating;
 print(t);
 std::sort(t.begin(), t.end());
 std::cout << "sorted:" << formating;
 print(t);
 auto itr_begin = doubleEraser(t.begin(), t.end());
 std::cout << "dEraser:" << formating;
 print(t);
 t.erase(itr_begin, t.end());
 std::cout << "output:" << formating;
 print(t);
}

int main()
{
 std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,3,5,6,7,2};
 std::vector<char> vec2 {'A', 'C', 'D', 'D', 'G', 'A' };
 std::vector<std::string> vec3 {"Hello", "World", "that", "be", "that", "Hello"};

 process(vec);
 process(vec2);
 process(vec3);
}`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. That's a very good first question though you should double check your formatting ;)

Comment: This question would be better off on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `Before presenting code, what im hoping for: code critique, critque using std::rotate`, excuse me?

Comment: Questions which are about general code advice are a better match for Code Review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Code Review.

Comment: Not sure of expected behavior of triplet (`{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}`) ? keep one or remove all ? (currently you keep one)

Comment: From your description, you are actually starting with two separate sets (`{downloaded}` and `{available}`), in which case `std::set_difference` is much shorter to write.

Comment: Thanks, i moved the code review part as suggested. And rephrased the question, I hope it is now appropriate for stackoverflow.

Comment: T.C. mentioned `std::set<>` - if you switch to that from `std::vector<>`, your `.insert(value)` statements will discard duplicates.  Given the set of available podcasts and the set of downloaded ones, `set_difference` can conveniently remove the already-downloaded ones. You shouldn't use "hashes" in the hash-function-generating-hash-numbers sense, but perhaps you mean "sets" anyway (I appreciate that some languages like Ruby refer to what computing science refers to as "hash tables" and C++ implements as "unordered_set" and "unordered_map" as "hashes").

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach requiring more space complexity. Map unique values and their indexes in reverse order, then just sort by indexes form a helper vector. Similar can be done for `string` but requires specific compare function.
Edit: for more complete example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>


template <typename T>
struct cmp
{
    bool operator()(std::pair<T, int>& a,
                    std::pair<T, int> & b)
    {
        return  a.second < b.second;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename Predicate_T>
class RemoveDups
{
    std::map<T, int> m_mapped;
    std::vector<std::pair<T, int>> m_sorted;
public:
    std::vector<T> operator()(const std::vector<T> in)
    {
        std::vector<T> ret;
        ret.reserve(in.size());
        for(int i=in.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)
            m_mapped[in[i]] = i;

        for(auto it : m_mapped)
            m_sorted.push_back(it);

        std::sort(m_sorted.begin(), m_sorted.end(), Predicate_T());
        for (auto it : m_sorted)
            ret.push_back(it.first);
        return ret;
    }
};


int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v          =   {1,1, 2, 2, 7, 2, 2, 7, 7, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 3, 2, 3, 2, 6, 2, 3, 2, 9, 10, 1, 2, 2, 1};
    std::vector<std::string> s =    {"world", "hello", "there", "world", "man", "there", "john", "doe", "doe", "john"};

    RemoveDups<int, cmp<int>> c;
    v = c(v);
    RemoveDups<std::string, cmp<std::string>> vs;
    s = vs(s);

    for(auto p : v)
        std::cout << p<< " ";
    std::cout << "\r\n";
    for(auto ps : s)
        std::cout << ps << " ";
    std::cout << "\r\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think what you're describing (or certainly what you want) is [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) . It removes all consecutive duplicates in the range (so more than just two duplicates like your algorithm). To work, std::unique requires that the input range is sorted and is implemented as follows:

```
template<class ForwardIt>
ForwardIt unique(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if (first == last)
        return last;

    ForwardIt result = first;
    while (++first != last) {
        if (!(*result == *first)) {
            *(++result) = std::move(*first);
        }
    }
    return ++result;
}
```

Comment: `std::unique` keeps one copy. The OP wants elements with duplicates to go away entirely (like `uniq -u`).